# Managing deletion on a large production SQL database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

We have a large SQL production DB (~1TB) that needs to be trimmed periodically and kept at a reasonable size. (i.e. every week trimming the oldest week of data so we consistently have X weeks of data) However, this DB is very active, and any large SQL operations will kill the performance of our product. I've written a stored procedure with a little pyodbc wrapper to chunk deletion into smaller, manageable operations.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PurgeTickerHistory]
@Start bigint = 0, 
@End bigint = 0,
@ChunkSize int = 10000
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @r int = 1;


while @r > 0
begin
    delete top(@ChunkSize)
        from dbo.TickerHistory
        where [Timestamp] < @Start and [Timestamp] > @End

    set @r = @@ROWCOUNT
end

end
```

Is this a completely viable way to go about this? Alternatively, are there 'better' ways to accomplish what I'm doing in a more efficient/safer manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly viable.   We have done something similar in my current shop, and my previous two (since 2005 made windows functions available).